# C# - LINQ Including headache

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

Case can have many Replies and one User, Replies can have one Case and one User, One User can have many Replies and many Cases.

*ObjectSet <= Case Object (IDbSet)*

```
ObjectSet.Include(x => x.User).Include(x => x.Replies).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == caseId);
```

But the User Object for each Reply are not included? Only the User object for Case is Included?

How would I include the User objects for the Replies too?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like that:

```
ObjectSet.Include(x => x.User)
         .Include(x => x.Replies.Select(r => r.User))
         .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == caseId);
```

If it doesn't work, try to specify the include as a string:

```
ObjectSet.Include(x => x.User)
         .Include("Replies.User")
         .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == caseId);
```